# Not able to establish connection via SqlHelper class

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlhelper

```
   string strCon =
           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;


           Company.Common.SqlHelper.Connect = strCon;
```

Getting this exception someone please help

```
"The type initializer for 'Company.Common.SqlHelper' threw an exception."}
```

---

```
  /// <summary>
/// The SqlHelper class is intended to encapsulate high performance, scalable best practices for 
/// common uses of SqlClient
/// </summary>
public sealed class SqlHelper
{
    public void MessageBox(string message, Control ControlID)
    {

        //tmp = "<script language='javascript'>";
        string tmp = "alert('" + message + "');";
        //tmp += "</script>";
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "tmp", tmp, true); 
        //string CloseWindow;
        //CloseWindow = "alert('Hello World')";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(ControlID, ControlID.GetType(), "tmp", tmp, true);
        // Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", tmp);
    }
    public static string Connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    #region private utility methods & constructors

    // Since this class provides only static methods, make the default constructor private to prevent 
    // instances from being created with "new SqlHelper()"
    private SqlHelper() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to attach array of SqlParameters to a SqlCommand.
    /// 
    /// This method will assign a value of DbNull to any parameter with a direction of
    /// InputOutput and a value of null.  
    /// 
    /// This behavior will prevent default values from being used, but
    /// this will be the less common case than an intended pure output parameter (derived as InputOutput)
    /// where the user provided no input value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The command to which the parameters will be added</param>
    /// <param name="commandParameters">An array of SqlParameters to be added to command</param>
    private static void AttachParameters(SqlCommand command, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");
        if (commandParameters != null)
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter p in commandParameters)
            {
                if (p != null)
                {
                    // Check for derived output value with no value assigned
                    if ((p.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput ||
                        p.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input) &&
                        (p.Value == null))
                    {
                        p.Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    command.Parameters.Add(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Which line is giving you exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is that there is no connection string on your config file with name `Constr` as, according error description, the problem should be on this line

```
public static string Connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing the type initializer for `SqlHelper` appears to be doing is this:

```
public static string Connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

What exception is this throwing?  If I were to guess, there probably isn't a connection string called `Constr` in the configuration.  Is there?  Can you show the config setting to us?  Otherwise, what is the exception?

Note also that `.ToString()` isn't necessary on that line.  `ConnectionString` is already a string.